# Replicate lines between two SAP systems

Tags: replication, abap

Is there a way to replicate some lines from one SAP system to a second SAP system?

[image: Replicate-lines-between-sap-systems]

In above example I would like to replicate all lines with `BUCHK=789` from SAP-1 to SAP-2.

There are roughly ten tables involved and all modifications to this tables will be done in SAP-1. In SAP-2 these lines won't get modified.

For every table there will be not more than 20 lines which should get replicated.

The tables which should get replicated do not change often. It would be enough if the tables get replicated daily or every 12 hours. Both SAP systems are in the same network.

Comment: typically you wouldn't directly replicate item lines in tables between SAP systems. You can often send data through IDocs from one system to another, for instance to generate GL bookings in a secondary system. You could even generate your own IDoc type and implement that kind of transfer for custom tables or parts of the SAP standard that don't come with their own IDoc type and function modules for IDoc processing.

Comment: Is this a one-off thing or you need it to happen near real-time or batched? Also is this client to client on the same box or is it different boxes? Different network or same network?

Comment: instead of keeping dublicates, why not write an RfC to access the data from SAP-1 on SAP-2 or the other way around? Or even and OData Service

Comment: @MikeWatson I updated the question: The tables which should get replicated do not change often. It would be enough if the tables get replicated daily or every 12 hours. Both SAP systems are in the same network.

Comment: @Erch legacy code which is not in our circle of influence reads the data from the tables. I can't modify this code. If I could, I would do solve it with RfC and use **one** central data storage.

Comment: @guettli i guess its time evaluate if it is more work, to refactor your old code or to find a just as ... not nice ... solution. "Always leave the code cleaner than you found it"

Comment: Is it a custom table? If standard what is the name? Also what timestamps do you have to play with in the data?

Comment: @MikeWatson it is a table from Z_ISU. What do you mean with "timestamps"?

Comment: Timestamps - that could be used to determine when a record has been created or changed. Having one in the table opens up some options.

Comment: Why not to set up update triggers directly on db level? If the servers have the same db-backend it is very easy to create [linked connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). ECC has no built-in tools for data replication, you need separate tool (SLT, BODS, MDM, MDG, etc.)